# Add column to the right jQuery table

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code that I tried so far but it is not giving me the results that I want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".get_attr").click(function (){
    var trow;//=$('.optionsForm tr:first').html();
    trow='<tr><th>Class</th><tr><td>sdfg</td></tr><tr><td>sdfg</td></tr><tr><td>sdfg</td></tr><tr><td>sdfg</td></tr></tr>';
    $('.optionsForm ').append(trow);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
      
  <table border="1" class='optionsForm'>
    <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
    <tr><td>sdg</td></tr>
    <tr><td>sdfg</td></tr>
    <tr><td>sdgds</td></tr>
  </table>

  <button type="button" data-id="5" class="get_attr" >Click Me</button>
</body>
```

When I click the button the colon is added just fine the `th` and other `td` but I want all this to be added to the right side something like this

```
Name    Class
sdg     sdg
sdfg    sdfg
sdgds   sdfgds
```

and not like this :

```
Name
sdg
sdfg
sdgds

Class
sdfg
sdfg
sdfg
sdfg
```

Can someone please give me a little help with this.

Comment: Check the html code ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you append whole html `<tr><th>Class</th><tr><td>sdfg</td></tr><tr><td>sdfg</td></tr><tr><td>sdfg</td></tr><tr><td>sdfg</td></tr></tr>`. You should append each `th`/`td` separately in thid `tr` you want. for example

```
$('.optionsForm tr:eq(0)').append('<th>Class</th>');
$('.optionsForm tr:eq(1)').append('<td>sdfg</td>');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".get_attr").click(function (){
    $('.optionsForm tr:eq(0)').append('<th>Class</th>');
    $('.optionsForm tr:eq(1)').append('<td>sdfg</td>');
    $('.optionsForm tr:eq(2)').append('<td>sdfg</td>');
    $('.optionsForm tr:eq(3)').append('<td>sdfg</td>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
      
  <table border="1" class='optionsForm'>
    <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
    <tr><td>sdg</td></tr>
    <tr><td>sdfg</td></tr>
    <tr><td>sdgds</td></tr>
  </table>

  <button type="button" data-id="5" class="get_attr" >Click Me</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".get_attr").click(function (){
    var trow;   
    var columnContent = ['Class', 'sdfg', 'sdfg', 'sdfg'];
    
    for(var i=0; i<columnContent.length; i++){
      if(i==0){
        $('.optionsForm ').find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').append('<th>' + columnContent[i] + '</th>');
      } else {
        $('.optionsForm ').find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').append('<td>' + columnContent[i] + '</td>');
      }
    }
   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
      
  <table border="1" class='optionsForm'>
    <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
    <tr><td>sdg</td></tr>
    <tr><td>sdfg</td></tr>
    <tr><td>sdgds</td></tr>
  </table>

  <button type="button" data-id="5" class="get_attr" >Click Me</button>
</body>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: While marking as negative, please provide explanation as well

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you have to add the new `td´s` for each existing `tr`, to make this you could make an array and then loop it, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".get_attr").click(function() {
    var cont = 1;
    var val = ["<td>sdfg1</td>", "<td>sdfg2</td>", "<td>sdf3g</td>", "<td>sdfg4</td>"];

    $("tr:first").append("<th>Class</th>");
    for(var i in val){
      $("tr").eq(cont).append(val[i]);
      cont++;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class='optionsForm'>
  <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
  <tr><td>sdg</td></tr>
  <tr><td>sdfg</td></tr>
  <tr><td>sdgds</td></tr>
</table>

<button type="button" data-id="5" class="get_attr" >Click Me</button>
```